# Hibernate is not using the proxy of a session scope bean spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm using Spring `@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)` beans for objects that should be shared across a single `Http-Session`. This will provide for example one "Project" object for each User who is using my application.

To get this working I had to implement an interceptor for Hibernate that is returning the name of the class:

```
public class EntityProxySupportHibernateInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7470168733867103334L;

    @Override
    public String getEntityName(Object object) {
        return AopUtils.getTargetClass(object).getName();
    }

}
```

With this interceptor I can use a Spring `CrudRepository` to save a Project-entity in the database:

```
@Repository
public interface ProjectRepository extends CrudRepository<Project, Integer> {

    Project findByProjectId(int projectId);

}
```

Project-entity:

```
@Component
@Entity
@Table(name = "xxx.projects")
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class Project implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8071542032564334337L;

    private int projectId;
    private int projectType;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "project_id")
    public int getProjectId() {
        return projectId;
    }

    public void setProjectId(int projectId) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
    }

    @Column(name = "project_type")
    public int getProjectType() {
        return projectType;
    }

    public void setProjectType(int projectType) {
        this.projectType = projectType;
    }
}
```

Storing the Project in the database works as expected. I can have a look at the database and the correct values are inserted. Now I have a different entity that I'm creating the same way as the project and that I want to save in the database via a CrudRepository.

Here the problem begins. Hibernate is not inserting the values that I have set. Hibernate always only inserts `null` into the database. Reading the values in my Spring application is working as expected. I think that Hibernate is not using the proxy of the entity but the underlying blueprint of the object. How can I force Hibernate to use the proxy with the correct values?

Repository:

```
@Repository("DataInput001Repository")
public interface DataInputRepository extends CrudRepository<DataInput, DataInputId> {}
```

Entity:

```
@Component("DataInput001")
@Entity
@Table(name = "xx.data_input_001")
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
@IdClass(DatanputId.class)
public class DataInput implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6941087210396795612L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "project_id")
    private int projectId;

    @Column(name = "income")
    private String income;
    @Column(name = "income_increase")
    private String incomeIncrease;

    /* Getter + Setter */
}
```

Service:

```
@Service("DataInputService001")
public class DataInputServiceImpl implements DataInputService {

    @Resource(name = "DataInputMapper001")
    DataInputMapperImpl dataInputMapper;

    @Resource(name = "DataInput001Repository")
    DataInputRepository dataInputRepository;

    @Resource(name = "DataInput001")
    DataInput datanInput;

    @Transactional
    public void createDataInput(String json) throws Exception {

        dataInputMapper.mapDataInput(json);
        dataInputRepository.save(dataInput);

    }

    public DataInput getDataInput() {
        return dataInput;
    }

    public void setDataInput(DataInput dataInput) {
        this.dataInput = dataInput;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why? Making entities session scoped is trouble waiting to happen. Just store them in the session/between page requests instead of making the session scoped. Saves you a lot of working around hibernate (which uses proxy as well) and replacing a proxy with a proxy (which would happen if you do a lookup and assign the entity looked in the field).

Comment: My idea behind that was to be able to just user `@Autowired` to retrieve the e.g. project entity for the current session. This way multiple users can create there own project and no other user can access the entity. @m-deinum you mean to store the object in the spring session and than retrieving it from the current session attribute when needed?

Comment: You don't need a session-scoped object for that. Also storing it in the session doesn't mean no-one else can access it. If it is an existing entity being edited it is still accessible. If you want to store it between requests in the session use `@SessionAttributes` instead of a session scoped object.

Comment: So when is it better use the session-scoped object than `@SessionAttributes`?

Comment: When it is an object that really needs to be scoped to a session but not stored, for instance a shopping cart for an online shop.